# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 only once

Tags: android, adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I got the following exception only once at `getItem` of adapter.Maybe it was a device or connection problem but my app crashed.How can i make sure that my app doen't crashes with this exception if there is problem in device?

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

adapter

```
   @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }
```

Comment: Use Exception handling to avoid ANR

Comment: Or how about you actually check the size of your container before trying to get an item?

Comment: @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            if(items.size()==0) return 0;
            return items.get(position);
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
      if(items.size() == 0) {
            return null;
      }
      return items.get(position);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to resolve this:

**1st** way:

You should add below code in your **BaseAdapter**:

```
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
 }
```

It will return number of elements of ArrayList.

In your case if ArrayList is empty than it will return 0 so `getItem(int pos)` will not call.

**2nd** way:

```
if(!item.isEmpty()){
  // Set Adapter Here
}else{
 // No data in ArrayList
}
```

Hope it will help you.